# Yii Update the database from a dropDownList

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i try without success to update the database from a dropDownList of a CGridView.

here is the code of the CGridView:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'invoice-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(     

    'id',

    'username',

       array(
            'name'  => 'state',
            'type'  => 'raw',
            'value' => '$data->stateDropdown',
            'filter' => array('0' => Yii::t('app', 'No'),
                              '1' => Yii::t('app', 'Yes'),
                             ),
       ),

    array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

Here is the getter of the function **stateDropDown()** in the Model:

```
public function getStateDropdown()
{
    $state = array(
            0 => 'No',
            1 => 'Yes',
    );
    return CHtml::dropDownlist('state', $this->state, $state, array(
            'class'    => 'state',
            'data-id'  => $this->id,
            'onchange' => 'alert(0);',
    ));
}
```

When I change the dropDownList element, the alert script is triggered, but when i try to use a function instead, i have an error. I want to use this function described below  to update the value of state in the database.

```
function updateState($state, $id)
{
$user = User::model()->findByPk($id);
$user->state = $state;
$user->update();
}
```

**How can i really call the function updateState() in place of alert(0)**

Comment: Why you are referring to yii2 tag while your code seems for Yii1 ?

Comment: @scaisEdge A yii1 or yii2 solution will help me. Maybe someone can have a yii2 solution to solve my problem.

Comment: you can't update database like this, at most you can filter database with grid, if so, also you're doing it wrong

Comment: @tinybyte I can filter the database. But what i want is how to update the database field " state" after selecting an option from a dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

quick answer: use [x-editable extension](http://x-editable.demopage.ru/index.php?r=site/widgets#EditableColumn), which has done an impressive job

other wise, you have to build something exactly like that,

make user select an item from your list, then make ajax request to save that change